# Can we relate the spectrum of a non-symmetric matrix to its (skew-) symmetric component?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $X$ be a non-symmetric square matrix and define $S=\frac{1}{2}(X+X^T)$ and $A=\frac{1}{2}(X-X^T)$.

Is there any result that somehow relates $\lambda(X)$, the spectrum of $X$, to $\lambda(S)$ and $\lambda(A)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a result from Bhatia's *Matrix Analysis* that you might find useful:

> **Theorem VI.2.2:** Let $A$ be a Hermitian matrix and $B$ a skew Hermitian matrix. Let their eigenvalues $\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n$ and $\beta_1,\dots,\beta_n$ be arranged is such a way that
> $$
> |\alpha_1| \geq \cdots \geq |\alpha_n| \quad \text{ and } \quad |\beta_1| \geq \cdots \geq |\beta_n|.
> $$
> Then
> $$
> \max_{j} |\alpha_j - \beta_{n - j + 1}| \leq \|A - B\|.
> $$

In the above, $\|A\|$ denotes the spectral norm (maximal singular value) of $A$. Now, if we set $A$ in the above to be $S$ and $B$ in the above to be $-A$, then we come to the conclusion that
$$
\|X\| = \|S - (-A))\| \geq \max_j|\alpha_j - \beta_{n-j+1}| = \max_j \sqrt{\alpha_j^2 + |\beta_{n-j+1}|^2},
$$
where the $\alpha_k,\beta_k$ denote the eigenvalues of $S$ and $A$ respectively indexed as in the theorem above. Note that $\|X\|$ is larger than the spectral radius of $X$ (maximal eigenvalue magnitude of $X$).

Comment: Thanks a lot! But isn't the inequality $||S-(-A)|| \leq \displaystyle\max_j \ldots$ should be in the opposite direction?

Comment: @June You're welcome. And yes, that was a typo